# Efficient way to replace int in list with first occurrence index

Tags: c#, linq, list, unity-game-engine, 3d

I am looking for a way to replace every int element in a list with the index of its first occurrence in a separate Distinct list. For example, take the following list:

```
<50, 2, 4, 5, 43, 42, 44, 14, 50, 44, 23, 2, 16, 4, 5, 23, 33 ... >
```

The distinct list would read like this:

```
<50, 2, 4, 5, 43, 42, 44, 14, 50, 23, 33 ... >
```

I would like for the list to read as follows:

```
<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 6, 8, 1, 9, 3, 4, 8, 10 ...>
```

I am new to LINQ operators, but I have the following code:

```
//Retrieve original list:
List<int> SubFaceList = FaceList.GetRange (faceBounds [fb], faceBounds [fb + 1]);

// Get unique face list entries:
List<int> UniqueFaceList = SubFaceList.Distinct ().ToList ();

//Replace values with first ocurrence:
List<int> RestructuredList = SubFaceList.Select ((vx,ix) => UniqueFaceList.IndexOf(vx)).ToList();
```

I am doing this, in order to split up a large Collada triangular 3D mesh, into smaller submeshes. The arrays are face construction order, which reference an index of vertices in a separate array, so numbers could be referenced multiple times in the face array. However, upon executing my code, some meshes take upwards of 30 minutes to process.

I also have the following code, which extracts the given vertices from the main vertex array, which does not seem to suffer from the same crippling inefficiency:

```
List<Vector3> subVertices = Vertices.Where ((vx, ix) => UniqueFaceList.Contains (ix)).Select (vx => vx).ToList();
```

Am I going about this wrong, and is there a potential way that I could extract the index based on the current vertex being processed in this statement? I know there has to be a more efficient way to get the information that I need, but I am not quite sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with LINQ, but if you want maximum performance, you could use `Dictionary` and simple `for` / `foreach` loop (you'll find that the code is not so bigger than the most efficient LINQ solution):

```
var indexMap = new Dictionary<int, int>();
var RestructuredList = new List<int>(SubFaceList.Count); // final capacity
foreach (var item in SubFaceList)
{
    int index;
    if (!indexMap.TryGetValue(item, out index))
        indexMap.Add(item, index = indexMap.Count);
    RestructuredList.Add(index);
}
```

Comment: I've been waiting for a solution without linq because it says "Efficient" in the title. All other answers used too much linq. This looks promising with Dictionary.

Comment: Thank you. This helped immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Store value and index to dictionary.

```
var faceList = new List<int>{ 50, 2, 4, 5, 43, 42, 44, 14, 50, 44, 23, 2, 16, 4, 5, 23, 33};
var uniqueList = new Dictionary<int,int>();
var restructuredList = new List<int>();
var i = 0;
faceList.ForEach(f =>
{
  if (uniqueList.ContainsKey(f))
  {
    restructuredList.Add(uniqueList[f]);
    return;
  }
restructuredList.Add(i);
uniqueList.Add(f, i++);
});
```